# can i replace single 20 amp breaker with double 20 amp

Tags: circuit-breaker, replacement

I had a single 20amp outside breaker with one red and one black wire connected to it. it kept flipping. i had unused double 20amp breaker. i put red wire in one spot and black wire in other of double 20amp breaker. is that safe or not

Comment: Why does it keep flipping?  When the breaker trips, what loads lose power?   Are you talking about a [tandem](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc) breaker (because no, that is not safe at all).

Comment: A picture of the panel and a list of what loads are currently powered by the circuit would help.

Comment: Do the red and black wires lead into the same cable or different cables?  What are you trying to run on the circuits in question?  What do you mean by a "double 20A breaker"?

Answer (score 1):

Man oh Man>>>>>>  no way.  I don't do be mean, but you obviously have no idea where these cables lead or how they are connected , could be a MWBC  could be an repurposed cable....you just can't know until you test and test some more until you know where this stuff goes.  you'll need a multi-meter and test that circuit thoroughly . Regularly tripping a breaker is a major issue and and dangerous .     You may need to call a pro.

Comment: Well regularly tripping a breaker may be as simple as the user intentionally overloading it because they want more stuff to work than the circuit can safely power.

Comment: And it may be that the red/black used to be two separate breakers and now doubled up under one breaker and separating is a *good* thing. Or it could be something else and separating could end up with causing all kinds of problems. *Too many unknowns*.